# Can members of congress carry weapons into the chamber?

Tags: united-states, congress, police, guns, washington-dc

Congresswoman Boebert has stated that she will bring a loaded glock into the DC. The article [here](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2021/jan/05/republican-lauren-boebert-gun-congress-washington) says that weapons can be carried around the streets of Washington D.C but a permit is required. However on the grounds of the capitol itself, members of congress, but not the public, can carry weapons without a permit as it is federal land.

My question is, whilst Boebert may be allowed to carry weapons in and around the grounds of the capitol, does this extend to her being able to bring her glock into the chamber itself? (I'm sure there's a pun in there somewhere). I have looked, but haven't found if there is a law that distinguishes whether members of congress can carry arms into a sitting session / chamber or laws regarding open carry in a crowded indoor place.

A follow up question I have is, should Boebert be allowed to carry her weapon in, and is deemed to be acting dangerously with it, can the sergeant at arms remove her from the chamber and does such an act only come from the authority of the Speaker?

Comment: The Constitution says that the House and Senate can make their own rules, so the House could make a rule either allowing or forbidding its members to carry weapons.  (Just as a private business or individual can e.g. forbid people from going armed on their property.)

Comment: This would certainly lead to "The only way to stop the filibuster of a bad guy with a gun is a good guy with a gun"

Comment: Observation, English members of Parliament and Lords have been forbidden from wearing armour or carrying swords since 30th October 1313. Sword hooks are provided in the cloakrooms for the use of Noble Lords. It's one of the oldest English laws, from a time when laws were still written in NormanFrench

Comment: @JamesK - Members of the Commons may not speak between two red lines on the carpet of each chamber, in front of their benches, 13 feet apart, said to be the length of two swords. I don't think this is so in the Lords.

Comment: Of course, by the time the current chamber was built, the law on swords had been in effect for hundreds of years, and in the old chamber (the one that burnt down) the two sides were closer together (it was a much smaller room)  The actual laws states "Sanz tote force et sanz armes" *without all weapons and without armour*. So guns and bulletproof jackets are also banned in Parliament.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article you link to says the answer is no.

> A 1967 law that prohibits members of the public from carrying guns on Capitol grounds was signed by President Lyndon Johnson. Regulations created by the police board days later exempted members of Congress from the law **but still prohibited them from carrying firearms in either legislative chamber.**